# How to reset the last Open/Save/Save As folder used by a program/file type?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry

I'm using a relatively old program that seems to have a bug which causes the program to not remember the last folder I opened (or saved) a file from.

Basically, everything is working fine but once a certain bug triggers, it doesn't remember the last folder I used and always starts from its own directory.

If I change the program directory (e.g. copy it to a new folder), it works fine until the bug triggers again.

I think there should be some registry address that remembers the last Open/Save folder.

After some digging, I found the following keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\OpenSavePidlMRU
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRU
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRULegacy
```

but deleting them didn't reset this setting.

Does anyone know the actual registry address that stores the Open/Save paths?

Comment: Have you used ProcMon to see what registry keys are queried by the program? Is it so old that it might save its settings in a file?

Comment: I tried Process Explorer, but couldn't find anything useful. I'll try ProcMon too